# Stacking data with excel/vba

Tags: vba

I have a lot of data in this form (wide)

[Original data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8VXxl.png)

I would need to transform it to "long form" like this:

[Transformed data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRjOZ.png)

How could I do this using excel (vba)? I do not need to have the headers for the data, just the raw data pasted "stacked" with different years.

Thanks

VBA I have tried

````
Dim OrigA
Dim OrigB
Dim strA As String
Dim strB As String
Dim strDelim As String
Dim lngCol As Long

strDelim = "||"
strA = Join(Application.Transpose(Range([a1], Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))), strDelim)
strB = Join(Application.Transpose(Range([b1], Cells(Rows.Count, "b").End(xlUp))), strDelim)

For lngCol = Columns("C").Column To Columns("ALC").Column - 2 Step 2
    If Application.CountA(Columns(lngCol)) > 1 Then
    'handle odd column range
        strA = strA & (strDelim & Join(Application.Transpose(Range(Cells(1, lngCol), Cells(Rows.Count, lngCol).End(xlUp))), strDelim))
    Else
    'handle odd column single cell
        If Len(Cells(1, lngCol)) > 0 Then strA = strA & (strDelim & Cells(1, lngCol).Value)
    End If
      If Application.CountA(Columns(lngCol + 1)) > 1 Then
      'handle even column range
    strB = strB & (strDelim & Join(Application.Transpose(Range(Cells(1, lngCol + 1), Cells(Rows.Count, lngCol + 1).End(xlUp))), strDelim))
    Else
     'handle even column single cell
    If Len(Cells(1, lngCol + 1)) > 0 Then strB = strB & (strDelim & Cells(1, lngCol + 1).Value)
    End If
Next

OrigA = Application.Transpose(Split(strA, strDelim))
OrigB = Application.Transpose(Split(strB, strDelim))

[a1].Resize(UBound(OrigA, 1), 1) = OrigA
[b1].Resize(UBound(OrigB, 1), 1) = OrigB

End Sub```
````

Comment: Have you tried anything?

As others have pointed out to me on here - its better for folks' learning if they have a stab at it than await a solution presented to them. Then go from their attempt to a working solution.

Comment: I have tried both powerquery and VBA for this but have not found a way to solve this.

Comment: Can you post up the VBA you've tried.

It is straightforward enough to copy the individual blocks, then paste them down beneath each other. You just need put a bit of thought into how you get the range boundaries.

Comment: I have copy pasted my VBA code to the original post

Answer (score 0):

I can't quite follow the blocks of data in the two links - it looks like its mostly taking a range from columns 2-9, then range of columns 10-17 and then I assume 18-25?

But the 2009 entry for columns 10-17 doesn't exist again 2009 in column A of the output, which leaves me confused???

Assuming that is a typo, and your collecting conventional blocks of unknown height and a known width you'd collate using:

```
Sub test1()

sourceSheet = "Sheet1"
destSheet = "Sheet2"

wCols = 7  'The width of the dataset on the source sheet
sCol1 = 2  'The starting column of the dataset we want to grab on the source sheet
sRow1 = 2  'The starting row of the dataset we want to grab on the source sheet

sRow2 = 2  'The starting row of where we'll paste the data on destSheet
sCol2 = 2  'The starting column of where we'll paste the data on destSheet

lastRow1 = Sheets(sourceSheet).Cells(Sheets(sourceSheet).Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

iCol1 = 0
iRows2 = 0
Do Until IsEmpty(Sheets(sourceSheet).Cells(sRow1, sCol1 + iCol1))
    Range(Sheets(sourceSheet).Cells(sRow1, sCol1 + iCol1), Sheets(sourceSheet).Cells(lastRow1, sCol1 + iCol1 + wCols - 1)).Copy

    Sheets(destSheet).Cells(sRow2 + iRows2, sCol2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    iRows2 = iRows2 + (lastRow1 - sRow1 + 1)

    iCol1 = iCol1 + wCols
Loop
```

End Sub

Not sure if this is exactly what your looking with the uncertainty around those image lines, but hopefully it'll steer you in the right direction.

But its nothing like the code you've presented! So pretty sure I'm missing something - why are you working with strings?

Comment: Thanks, the data is incomplete but the basic idea is to just stack the columns in "7 column blocks" on top of each other, tried your code but excel crashed

Comment: Hmm, it worked here on a simple test set.

How big is your sheet? (and do you have it created/saved as an .xlsm with 1048576 rows)?

Try stepping through with F8 and breakpoints to see where it goes wrong.

Comment: Tested again and it worked, the data amount was just so huge that excel crashed first time. Thanks!